# Mixing sounds in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 wave (.wav) samples of 1 second duration each. I need to mix them such that the second wave file starts at 0.5 seconds after the first one. I need to export the mixed wave format to a new wave file called output.wav. How can I achieve this using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) will allow to mix audio files. You can specify offsets using the -p pad option.

```
sox -m sound1.wav "|sox sound2.wav -p pad 0.5" out.wav
```

Check question 7 of the [Sox FAQ](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/FAQ) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I quickly went through the documentation and figured out to do simple mixing of two audio files. However, I couldn't see how I can mix at an offset. Can you tell me, maybe with a core reference if this is possible in Sox?

Comment: Added an example of mixing sounds at offsets to my answer.

Comment: This does not work for me..It only plays one file :( Any ideas?