# Mix audio files with an offset(at particular points) using SOX

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg, pipe, sox, windows-console

I have two audio files one is 10 secs long and other is 17 secs long, I want to mix the files together so that the 17 sec file starts playing from the start, while the 10 sec file will start after 7 seconds into the 17seconds file.
How can I do this?

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084578/mixing-sounds-in-ffmpeg), I also tried other commands mentioned in Sox FAQ, question number 7, but I am unable to mix two files by providing an offset, I also tried the command in command line and the error is same.

The error which I see is

> option ` ' not recognized

and the command I used is

```
sox -m drums.wav "|sox beats.wav -p pad 1.5" out.wav
```

Edit: It seems to me that the pipe operator "|" is broken, how do I fix this?

My problem is exactly the same as mentioned in this [forum](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.audio.sox/3869)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am not able to solve this using "audionuma's" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's an issue with `"`.
Try

```
sox -m drums.wav '|sox beats.wav -p pad 1.5' out.wav
```

Comment: Thanks for answering it makes no difference, I am trying the command in windows console and the error I get is "error writing output file: Broken pipe"

Comment: Sorry, in fact this does work with bash on Mac OS X.8.  I don't have a Windows system. maybe a clue here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200235/how-to-pass-a-quoted-pipe-character-to-cmd-exe

Comment: which version of sox are you using? I am using 14.4.0

Comment: I have two audio files one is 10 secs long and other is 17 secs long, I want to mix the files together so that the 17 sec file starts playing from the start, while the 10 sec file will start after 7 seconds into the 17seconds file.
How can I do this?